# ggplot2 unexpected vapply error

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)

zzz <- data.frame(gp = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"), 
              c1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
              c2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

ggplot(zzz, aes(x = c1, y = c2)) +
  facet_wrap(~ gp, scales = "free", strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1,
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  )
```

Why do I get the following error? And how could I overcome it?

```
Error in vapply(row_axes, is.zero, logical(length(row_axes))) : 
values must be length 3,
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
```

Some tweaks I tested revealed that there is no issue if:

a) I remove one line in the data.frame or if I add 2 more lines with a new group for each, or

b) I remove `strip.placement = "outside"` or `strip.position = "bottom"`

Is that a bug? Did I miss something? I would like to keep the strip settings for aesthetics...

Comment: Indeed. Seems to be a bug if there are empty slots in a row together with the `"bottom"` parameter. Using `"left"` is working.

Comment: Yes, seems like a bug to me. You can report it [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues).

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2622

Comment: Issue had been addressed in the GH thread above. Current version of ggplot2 (3.1.0) no longer returns this error. Voting to close as the problem can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was in your code, it's in `scales/strip.plavcement`.

This code worked for me:

```
library(ggplot2)

zzz <- data.frame(gp = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"), 
                  c1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                  c2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
str(zzz)
zzz$c1=as.character(zzz$c1)
zzz$c2=as.character(zzz$c2)
ggplot(zzz, aes(x = c1, y = c2)) +geom_point() +
  # facet_wrap(~ gp, scales = "free", strip.position = "bottom") 
  facet_wrap(~gp,nrow=1,strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank())
  # theme(
  #   aspect.ratio = 1,
  #   strip.background = element_blank(),
  #   strip.placement = "outside")
```

The output is this...hope this helps [image: Output Plot]